# How to add 95% confidence error bars into bar graphs using R?

Tags: r

I am trying to add error bars into my bar graph but I can't. When I write the code:

```
 ggplot(data = GenIncom, aes(x = educ, y = appxincome, fill =sex)) +
     stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", position = "dodge", geom = "bar" )
```

I get:

[image]

but when I write my code to add error bars the graph disappears and there is blank or I might get the error bars without the actual bar graph. Here is my code for the error bars:

```
ggplot(data = naedu, aes(x = educ, y = appxincome, fill =sex)) +
    stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", position = "dodge", geom = "errorbar", 
    fun.data = mean_cl_normal)
```

and here is what I end up with:

[image]

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Have you tried `ggplot(data = GenIncom, aes(x = educ, y = appxincome, fill =sex)) + stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", position = "dodge", geom = "bar" )+stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", position = "dodge", geom = "errorbar", fun.data = mean_cl_normal)`?

Answer (score 1):

You are using two ggplot calls, essentially drawing a bar graph, and then redrawing the graph with only the error bars. Just include calls to stat_summary 2x.